# function name for @Provides Method in Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

With @Provides annotation, I am curious what is the function name requirement.

```
@Provides
TypeA ProvideTypeA()
{
...
return TypeA
}
```

Is it OK to use a different function name?

```
@Provides
TypeA AnyName()
{
...
return TypeA
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## The name is totally unimportant

You may call your method `foo`, `provideFoo` or `anyNameThatYouWant`, it won't matter.

The things that matter are the return-type, parameter-types and the binding annotations (if any, in addition to `@Provides`).